# Prove that the functional $A$ is continuous and calculate its norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Prove that the linear functional
$$
A(f) = \int_2^4 \left( x^3f(x) + \dfrac{if(x+1)}{x^2} \right)dx \quad \forall f \in L_2(\mathbb{R})
$$
is continuous and calculate its norm.

To solve this problem I computed the norm of $A$ directly. By doing so, we would prove that it is bounded, and since it is linear, that would imply its continuity. The way I tried to do this is by using the Riesz theorem. If I find a $g\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A(f) = \langle g,f \rangle$, then $\|A\| = \|g\|$.

$$
\begin{align}
A(f) &= \int_2^4 x^3 f(x)\ dx + \int_2^4 \dfrac{if(x+1)}{x^2}\ dx = \int_2^4 x^3 f(x)\ dx + \int_3^5 \dfrac{if(x)}{(x-1)^2}\ dx \\
&=\int_2^3 x^3 f(x)\ dx + \int_3^4 \left( x^3 + \dfrac{i}{(x-1)^2} \right) f(x)\ dx + \int_4^5 \dfrac{if(x)}{(x-1)^2}\ dx.
\end{align}
$$

Defining a function $g$ as
$$
g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
x^3 & \text{if } x \in [2,3] \\
x^3 - \dfrac{i}{(x-1)^2} & \text{if } x \in (3,4] \\
- \dfrac{i}{(x-1)^2} & \text{if } x \in (4,5] \\
0 & \text{in any other case}
\end{array}\right.
$$
it is clear that $A(f) = \langle g,f \rangle$, so
$$
\begin{align}
\|A\|^2 &= \|g\|^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(x)|^2 dx = \int_2^3 x^6\ dx + \int_3^4 \left(x^6 + \dfrac{1}{(x-1)^4}\right)dx + \int_4^5 \dfrac{1}{(x-1)^4}\ dx.
\end{align}
$$

The norm $\|A\|$ is finite, so the functional is bounded and, therefore, continuous.

Is this a correct approach? Have I make any mistake?

Comment: Looks good to me! You should go ahead and finish the integrals to get the norm, of course.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks for your fast answer! Also thanks for editing the symbol of the norm, I didn't realize it!

Comment: Sure, no problem! By the way, you can use `\left` and `\right` on norm symbols `\|` to get auto-sized ones, just like with parentheses. Very handy!